# c# Autocad Map 3D 2012 get user drawn object

Tags: c#, .net, autocad, objectarx

Is it possible to send a string to execute to Map and find out what objects has the user drawn in an easier way? I feel that like what I am doing is too much...

This is the command:

```
    acad.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument.SendStringToExecute
("_MPOLYGON ", false, false, true);
```

As of now, what I do is I subscribe to the object appended event, and to the command ended event, then I call the sendStringToExecute and from there I check all the new objects coming in the DB and keep a reference to the ones I find the user has drawn.

So first:

```
    HostApplicationServices.WorkingDatabase.ObjectAppended += 
new ObjectEventHandler(activeDB_ObjectAppended);
```

and

```
    acad.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument.CommandEnded += 
new CommandEventHandler(MdiActiveDocument_CommandEnded);
```

While the command is executing:

```
void activeDB_ObjectAppended(object sender, ObjectEventArgs e)
        {
            polyDessinIds.Add(e.DBObject.Id);
        }
```

Autocad adds objects to the database WHILE the _MPOLYGON command is being executed, so I keep a reference to all them. Autocad adds points and lines to the database while the user is drawing. For example, the first and second click that for a line seem to be put in the database. Also when a polygon is added to the working db it does not mean it is the last one. The last added object is not guaranteed to be the real object either.

Then when the command is ended, I look for the correct objectId, even if there are many polygons that were drawn, there is only 1 valid objectId that references the one or the many polygons drawn.

```
 foreach (ObjectId obj in polyDessinIds)
 {
            if (obj.IsErased == false && obj.ObjectClass.Name == "AcDbMPolygon")
            {
             mPolygons = obj;
             //there should be only one valid at this point
             break;
            }
 }
```

I am wondering if there is a better and more reliable way to do this? Maybe something like when you prompt for selecting objects, this returns a selection set with all the objects. Is there a way to "promptForPolygon" or something similar that will just return me the new objects once the user has drawn them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you need all of that code, try to play with:

```
ApplicationServices.Application.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument.Editor.SelectLast()
```

Which should give you the last entity drawn or used.

Some more explanation here:

```
http://72.77.202.9/index.php?topic=20267.0
```

Hope it helps.